# Wix Toolset: How to store file in a table in custom wix extension

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I am trying to create a custom Wix Extension which copies a file with come preparations.

How can I achieve the similar procedure to [File Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html) when all you need is specify file source and the file gets stored in the MSI tables?

```
<File Id="Some.dll"
      Source="files\Some.dll"
      KeyPath="yes" />
```

As a workaround I can use [Binary Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/binary.html), but I want to have the same elegant style as Wix Toolset.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add your file to the Binary table of the MSI. This page [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/icumove/2009/06/23/custom-action-using-wix-reading-from-the-binary-table/) shows how to do this and then utilize it while installing.